# Write-Host is not returning my variable data properly

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a CSV file to add a list of users to an AzureAD group I have set up in our tenant.  It appears that the script is working, but for some reason one particular write-host in one of my If statements is not showing my variable data as expected.  I am using the same variable in all of my other write-hosts and they all work so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

My CSV looks like this if it matters:

```
Name,InvitedUserEmailAddress
Test User01,testuser01@gmail.com
Test User02,testuser02@gmail.com
```

Here is my simplified PS snippet.

```
$users = import-csv "D:\UserListTest1.csv"
$groupID = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "TestGroup" | Select-Object ObjectId, displayname

foreach ($email in $users) {
    # Pull usersAAD email list from AzureAD
    $usersAAD = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $($email.InvitedUserEmailAddress) | Select-Object ObjectId, displayname, mail

    # Users from CSV not in AzureAD
    if ($usersAAD.mail -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "User $($usersAAD.displayname) does not exist in AzureAD" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else {
        # Pull AzureAD user group membership from users that exist in AzureAD
        $ExistingGroups = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $usersAAD.ObjectId | Select-Object displayname, objectid

        # Users that are already members of the AzureAD group
        if ($ExistingGroups.ObjectId -eq $groupID.objectId) {
            Write-Host "$($usersAAD.displayname) already exists in $($groupID.displayname)" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
        }
        else {
            # Add users to AzureAD group if they are not already part of AzureAD group
            Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupID.ObjectId -RefObjectId $usersAAD.ObjectId
            Write-Host "Added $($usersAAD.displayname) to $($GroupID.displayname)" -ForeGroundColor Green
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is with the write-host results from the If statements below which happens when the user is already in the group.

```
# Users from CSV not in AzureAD
if ($usersAAD.mail -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "User $($usersAAD.displayname) does not exist in AzureAD" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

In my example, testuser02@gmail.com does not exist in my AzureAD tenant, so I'm expecting a red text showing "User testuser02@gmail.com does not exist in AzureAD" for this user. Instead I see the following output.  Test User01 is working fine but my Test User02 is not.  Sorry for the bad formatting.

```
Test User01 already exists in TestGroup  
User  does not exist in AzureAD
```

Why would it have a null value for users that are already part of the group?  It even adds a space  to the output. I have tried removing the .displayname object as well but it doesn't help anything.

One odd thing that may have something to do with it is my $usersAAD variable seems to be empty after I run the whole thing.  If I do a write-host $usersAAD after the whole thing runs (even though it invites users properly), it doesn't return any results.

Comment: This can happen in the case that `$usersAAD =  Get-AzureADUser....` is `$null`, in which case you would be evaluating to `$null.mail -eq $null` which is `$true` and then entering that condition

Comment: I understand what you are saying, so thank you for clarifying that.  It does make sense now that you explain it.  I guess I need to instead do a write-host of the $users.displayname object if it matches one of the non existing users.  If anyone has suggestions on how to do that it would be appreciated!

Comment: Exactly, you should change `User $($usersAAD.displayname)...` for `User $($email.Name)...`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon your suggestion solved my issue.  Appreciate the help!  If you want to post it as an answer I will happily accept it.  I can't upvote comments yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in comments, `"User $($usersAAD.displayname) does not...` is referring to an object that does not exist (`$null`) when the condition `$usersAAD.mail -eq $null` is `$true`, which is why in your output you get `User  does not exist in AzureAD`. To fix this, you can refer to the item (`$email`) in your collection (***the Csv***).

Here is my take on your code and said fix included as well as some inline comments to help you with the thought process.

```
$groupID = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "TestGroup"

foreach ($email in Import-Csv "D:\UserListTest1.csv") {
    # if this user exists in Azure AD
    if ($usersAAD = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $email.InvitedUserEmailAddress) {
        # get the membership
        $ExistingGroups = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $usersAAD.ObjectId
        # and check if the test group is part of the user membership
        # (notice `-contains` here is faster than `-eq` !!!)
        if ($ExistingGroups.ObjectId -contains $groupID.objectId) {
            Write-Host "$($usersAAD.displayname) already exists in $($groupID.displayname)" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
            # if this condition was `$true` just go to the next item in our loop
            continue 
        }
        # if we're here above condition was `$false`, so add this user to the test group
        Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupID.ObjectId -RefObjectId $usersAAD.ObjectId
        Write-Host "Added $($usersAAD.displayname) to $($GroupID.displayname)" -ForeGroundColor Green
        # and go to next item in loop
        continue 
    }
    # if we're here we can assume the user did not exist in Azure AD, hence:
    Write-Host "User $($email.Name) does not exist in AzureAD" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```